# Страница не видит видео

Tags: html, css, git, github

Начал делать небольшую страницу. Есть проблема, после того как у себя написал этот код, у меня все видит и видео отыгрывается. После того, как я забросил код на репозиторий, на github, после загрузки всех файлов, страница не играет видео, хотя разметка вся есть и файл видео послался вместе с проектом. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Main_page.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <video src="/videos/main_page_video.mp4" typeof="video/mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    <div class="header_content">
        <div class="menu">
            <div><a href="#">Всі національні блюда</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Традиції</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Десерти</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Напої</a></div>
            <div><a href="#">Контакти</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В случае, когда видео не работает, каким образом открываете основную страницу? Какой url вводите? Вопрос в том где страница хостится? Какой веб сервер ее хостит и раздает?

Comment: @RomanKonoval просто открываю html файл

Comment: "просто открываю" - это непонятно. Это можно делать очень разными способами.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Есть главный html файл. Если я просто кликаю на него то оно видео не видит, когда пытаюсь открыть с помощью браузеров разных, так же его не видит

Comment: А вы запушили папку videos в репозиторий?

Comment: @ИванИпатов Да конечно. Даже если отправлять проект не через github, а просто архивом, так же не видит

Comment: Проблема в абсолютном пути к файлу. Это будет работать или на вебсервере, если `video` будет в корневой папке, или локально если опять же `video` папка в корне. Укажите относительный путь к файлу. В вопросе покажите структуру проекта, чтоб можно было точнее сказать.